# Cannot access Snap Store or Ubuntu Software on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-recommendation, software-center, snap-store

Whenever I click on the Ubuntu Software icon, it does not open. The same is true if I use snap store links. When I try to open the store via the command line, I receive this error:

```
$ snap run snap-store
ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-38-2004 content interface.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very rare situation, but can usually be resolved by re-attaching `snap-store` to the content interface.

Here's how you can do it:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Reattach the Snap:

   ```
   snap connect snap-store:gnome-3-28-2004 gnome-3-28-2004:gnome-3-28-2004
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** There is no output, so it will look like nothing has happened.</sup>
2. Open the Snap Store normally (or via the Terminal)

Hope this helps